# How to get Balance from property

Tags: c#

I have one class that contains simple data for transactions with one field for Amount which holds the transaction amount plus or minus, my question is how to calculate the Balance after each transaction **without using linq**, I want to know how this is done in merely pure programming.

this is the code for the Transaction Class:

```
using System;

namespace AccountSummary
{
    class masterTransData
    {
        public long TransNo { get; set; }
        public DateTime TransDate { get; set; }
        public long AccountNo { get; set; }
        public decimal Amount { get; set; }

        public decimal getBalance()
        {
            decimal[] Balance;
            masterTransData[] mtd = transData();
            for(int i=0; i<mtd.length; i++)
            {
                Balance[i] += mtd[i].amount; 
            }

            return Balance;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: balance shouldn't be an array - its your final total

Comment: You never `new` anything for `Balance`, thus it will be `null`. Use ` List<decimal>` instead if you don't know how many elements you will have and `.Add` to it.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably your balance is single value for the total amounts, not an array.

You asked for a solution without LINQ, but I thought it may be useful to show how this relates.  In LINQ, you would use the `Sum` extension method:

```
masterTransData[] mtd = transData();
var balance = mtd.Sum(x => x.amount);
```

`Sum` isn't particularly magic.  Once it has projected your items to get an `IEnumerable<decimal>` then, internally, it is doing this:

```
decimal sum = 0;
foreach (decimal v in source) 
{
    sum += v;
}
return sum;
```

So the imperative way of writing your code would be:

```
masterTransData[] mtd = transData();
decimal balance = 0;
foreach (var d in mtd) 
{
    balance += d.amount;
}
return balance;
```

What LINQ adds to the mix that's so preferable is that it separates the *intent* from the *implementation*.  This greatly improves readability.  I can look at the two line example and say 'ok, we're summing up all the amounts'.  If I want to know what's going on in more detail, I can drill down and inspect what the method is doing.  The alternative is reading 6 lines of code and having to reason about what it's doing.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `GetBalance` method to:

```
public decimal GetBalance()
{
    decimal balance;
    masterTransData[] mtd = transData();
    for(int i=0; i<mtd.length; i++)
    {
        balance += mtd[i].amount; 
    }

    return balance;
}
```

Comment: Working but not for all class data only for the first transaction.

Answer (score 0):

You must use a plain decimal variable to accumulate balance value

```
using System;

namespace AccountSummary
{
    class masterTransData
    {
        public long TransNo { get; set; }
        public DateTime TransDate { get; set; }
        public long AccountNo { get; set; }
        public decimal Amount { get; set; }

        public decimal getBalance()
        {
            decimal balance = 0M;
            masterTransData[] mtd = transData();
            for(int i=0; i<mtd.length; i++)
            {
                balance += mtd[i].amount; 
            }

            return balance;
        }
    }
}
```